# for range vs static channel length golang

Tags: for-loop, go, concurrency

I have a channel taking events parsed from a log file and another one which is used for synchronization. There were 8 events for the purpose of my test.

When using the `for range` syntax, I get 4 events. When using the known number (8), I can get all of them.

```
func TestParserManyOpinit(t *testing.T) {
    ch := make(chan event.Event, 1000)
    done := make(chan bool)
    go parser.Parse("./test_data/many_opinit", ch, done)
    count := 0
    exp := 8
    evtList := []event.Event{}

    <-done
    close(ch)
    //This gets all the events
    for i := 0; i < 8; i++ {
            evtList = append(evtList, <-ch)
            count++
    }

    //This only gives me four
    //for range ch {
    //        evtList = append(evtList, <-ch)
    //        count++
    //}

    if count != exp || count != len(evtList) {
            t.Errorf("Not proper lenght, got %d, exp %d, evtList %d", count, exp, len(evtList))
    }

func Parse(filePath string, evtChan chan event.Event, done chan bool) {
    log.Info(fmt.Sprintf("(thread) Parsing file %s", filePath))
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    defer file.Close()

    if err != nil {
            log.Error("Cannot read file " + filePath)
    }
    count := 0
    scan := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scan.Split(splitFunc)
    scan.Scan() //Skip log file header

    for scan.Scan() {
            text := scan.Text()
            text = strings.Trim(text, "\n")
            splitEvt := strings.Split(text, "\n")
            // Some parsing ...
            count++
            evtChan <- evt
    }

    fmt.Println("Done ", count) // gives 8
    done <- true
}
```

I must be missing something related to for loops on a channel.

I've tried adding a `time.Sleep` just before the `done <- true` part. It didn't change the result.

Comment: This is because all the values will not get passed to the channel and it quits before you wait for all the values to be printed.

Comment: @Himanshu `main` is not shown, so you cannot know if the program is exiting early or not; also the fact that it works with a `for` using a count implies that the issue is *not* early exit. The issue is most likely the misuse of `for range` with channels.

Comment: @Adrian there's no main, it's the testing suite (`go test`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `for range`, each loop iteration reads from the channel, and you're not using the read value. Hence, half the values are discarded. It should be:

```
for ev := range ch {
        evtList = append(evtList, ev)
        count++
}
```

In order to actually utilize the values read in the loop iterator.

Ranging over channels is demonstrated in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4) and detailed in the [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range).